# Событие input, проверка значения

Tags: javascript

Появляется тот блок с классом, которое передаётся через input.

Проблема в том, что, когда число стираешь, то в консоле появляется ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Не понимаю почему, я же написал условие, если такого элемента в массиве нет, то ничего делать не надо

```html
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.img1 {background: green;}
.img2 {background: blue;}
.img3 {background: red;}
</style>

<input type="text" class="input">

<div class="img img1 hidden"></div>
<div class="img img2 hidden"></div>
<div class="img img3 hidden"></div>

<script>
var input =  document.querySelector('.input');

var img = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

var arr = [];
img.forEach(function(el, i) {
  arr.push(i);
 })
 

input.oninput = function() {
 img.forEach(function(element, i) {
  
   if(arr.indexOf(Number(input.value)) != -1) {
     img[input.value - 1].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
   else{
     img[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    
  })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас выполняется вот это условие

```
if(arr.indexOf(Number(input.value)) != -1) {
    img[input.value - 1].classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

В случае если input.value = '' строка Number(input.value) вернет 0, а далее вы получаете img[input.value - 1], что равно img[-1], соответственно такого элемента нет в массиве. Переделайте проверку.

```
input.oninput = function() {
    img.forEach(function(element, i) {

    if(arr.indexOf(Number(input.value)-1) != -1) {
        img[Number(input.value - 1)].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    else{
        img[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: если написать img[input.value], то тоже будет ошибка

Comment: я уже напрямую вставляю, всё равно вылазит ошибка

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1gyd5z1t/

Comment: if(input.value == '') {
      img[0].classList.add('hidden');
    }
    if(arr.indexOf(Number(input.value)) != -1) {
    img[Number(input.value)].classList.remove('hidden');
    }

Comment: img[input.value] в случае если пустое значение будет искать элемент с ключем '', а не 0

Comment: как она может искать элемент ключом, если в поле пусто? Я этого вообще не понимаю

Comment: Если в поле пусто, это не означает, что событие oninput не происходит. Стирая все символы из поля ввода вы вызываете событие и значением поля является пустая строка, которая в свою очередь преобразуется при помощи Number(input.value) к 0. Поставте debugger в функции обработчике oninput и проанализируйте поведение когда. Все встанет на свои места. Дополнил ответ полностью рабочей функцией, которая не выводит ошибок.